# x86 Assembly - Which value is in ebx?

Tags: assembly, x86

> ```
> mov eax, 47
> push eax
> mov eax, 11
> push eax
> pop ebx
> ```
>
> Which value is located in ebx?

I'm not really sure what should be in ebx, probably a random value? On the stack, there should be (from high to low) 47, 11 but we know nothing about ebx. Is this just a trick question?

Comment: There is no "eax stack". There is only a single stack. So `ebx` will be `11` because `push eax` puts that `11` onto the stack last and `pop ebx` pops that.

Comment: Ok, thank you now it makes sense. So we pop the value and save it in ebx.

Comment: @Doesbaddel Correct.

Comment: And the value `47` remains on the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be easy if using tools called [rappel](https://github.com/yrp604/rappel)

So, what the value in `ebx` ? value in `ebx` is `11` or `0b` in hexadecimal number

```
eax: 0x0000000b ebx: 0x0000000b ecx: 0x00000000 edx: 0x00000000
esi: 0x00000000 edi: 0x00000000
eip: 0x00400002 esp: 0xbff7f1ac ebp: 0x00000000
flags: 0x00000202 [cf:0, zf:0, of:0, sf:0, pf:0, af:0, df:0]
```